# Объединение нескольких серверов по одному внешнему IP

Tags: apache, сервер, nginx, веб-сервер, роутер

Есть 3 физических вебсервера в локальной сети, внешний IP и домен. На один из вебсерверов проброшен 80 порт, два других доступны только в локальной сети. Каким образом можно настроить вебсервера так, чтобы когда мы пытаемся зайти, например, через поддомен `mail.domain.com`, который физически на втором вебсервере (`domain.com` грузится с первого сервера), можно было получить сайт с этого второго вебсервера (и все то же самое для третьего и последующих) который доступен только в локальной сети.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, какие темы. Может, есть ссылки на что-то похожее.

Comment: Nginx умеет использовать разные бэкенды для разных доменных имён. Пробрасываем порт на nginx, а он уже переправляет запрос на нужный сервер.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, это можно сделать с помощью [*http*-сервера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80), умеющего [*проксировать*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) *http*-запросы.

ту конфигурацию, как вам требуется, часто называют [*обратным проксированием*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8) (это частный случай проксирования).

[список наиболее распространённых реализаций прокси-серверов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B8.D0.B1.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B5_.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.91.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8-.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B):

- 3proxy (BSD, многоплатформенный)
- CoolProxy (проприетарный, Windows)
- Eserv (shareware, Windows)
- HandyCache (shareware, Windows) бесплатен для домашнего использования
- Kerio Control (проприетарный, Windows, Linux)
- Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway, ранее Microsoft ISA Server (proprietary, Windows)
- Blue Coat Proxy SG (аппаратный/виртуальный appliance)
- nginx (веб-сервер, имеющий режим работы в качестве reverse proxy и часто для этого использующийся)
- Squid (GPL, многоплатформенный)
- Traffic Inspector (проприетарный, Windows)
- UserGate (проприетарный, Windows)
- Интернет Контроль Сервер (shareware, FreeBSD)
- TOR (BSD, многоплатформенный)
- Ideco ICS (проприетарный, Linux)
- WinGate (проприетарный, Windows)
- Cntlm (с авторизацией)

---

но самым частоиспользуемым (особенно для *обратного проксирования*), пожалуй, является [*nginx*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). литературу можно посмотреть, например, в [описании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/nginx/info) метки [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx).