# Мульти сайты в docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

есть 3 сайта site1.loc, site2.loc, site3.loc
хочу всех запустить в docker. 1 сайт запустить получается, но не понимаю как запустить остальные.

как сделать для каждого сайта разные контейнеры. чтоб у каждого был свой php, mysql, phpadmin или это будет не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

всё точно так же, как и без упоминания слова «docker»:

- можно обслуживать несколько сайтов [одним экземпляром http-сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773770/178576)
- можно обслуживать каждый сайт (или по нескольку сразу) отдельным экземпляром http-сервера, воспользовавшись [http-proxy-сервером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554776/178576) (формально это называется [**обратным** прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8))

а программа «docker» всего лишь позволяет изолировать упомянутые экземпляры http-серверов (и http-proxy, в том числе) от остальных выполняющихся на компьютере процессов.